# Intel-x86, confused about the allocation of bytes in the esp register

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I've been a bit stuck on this question. Given the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 13

  int foo(){
    int i;
    int B[BUF_SIZE];
    for(i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++)
      B[i] = 5;
    return i;
  }

  int main(){
    foo();
    return 0;
  }
```

The following Intel-x86 assembly is generated:

```
1.           .file "code.c"
2.           .intel_syntax noprefix
3.           .text
4.           .globl foo
5.           .type foo, @function
6. foo:
7.           push ebp
8.           mov ebp, esp
9.           sub esp, 64
10.             mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 0
11.             jmp .L2
12.       .L3:
13.             mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
14.             mov DWORD PTR [ebp-56+eax*4], 5
15.             add DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 1
16.       .L2:
17.             cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 12
18.             jle .L3
19.             mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
20.             leave
21.             ret
22.             .size foo, .-foo
23.             .globl main
24.             .type main, @function
25.       main:
26.             push ebp
27.             mov ebp, esp
28.             call foo
29.             mov eax, 0
30.             pop ebp
31.             ret
32.             .size main, .-main
33.             .ident "GCC: (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516"
34.           .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'm a bit stuck trying to determine the meaning of line 9 in the assembly. My understanding is that we subtract from the stack register in order to allocate space on the stack for local variables. I know, then, that 52 bytes are being subtracted for the array `B`, and another 4 bytes for `i`. But I'm wondering where the other 8 bytes come from? Are those the return values of `foo` and `main`? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's probably for alignement purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of bytes added onto `esp` is rounded up to maintain some stack alignment. Imagine, you would only add `57` or something. A function you would call, would then need to realign the stack pointer first before storing a 4-byte integer. Everyone is saved that hassle if everyone keeps the stack aligned.

Comment: I see, so its adding 8 bytes as padding essentially?